# .gitignore that ignore all the files that have a peer with a *.in

Tags: gitignore

I have some generated files from templates. Let's say I have in my repository:

```
foo.c.in
bar.h.in
baz.html.in
```

These files could be generated through a Make rule:

```
$(wildcard *.in): %: %.in
    PYTHONPATH+=. mako-render $< > $@
```

I don't want to manually add each of these generated files to my `.gitignore`

```
foo.c
bar.h
baz.html
```

Is there a smarter way?

Comment: If you put the generated file in a separate directory, you can exclude that directory (and all its content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those two sets of files are the only one in a given folder, you can:

- ignore everything
- exclude the `*.in` files

That is

```
*
!*.in
```

But if those files are not alone, and in multiple folders, then, as commented, your `Makefile` would need to generate the list of files to ignore, either in:

- a dedicated `.gitignore`
- a dedicated file specified by the configuration variable `core.excludesFile`